# Given a clojure vector, iteratively remove 1 element

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to build a set of functions to compare sentences to one another. So I wrote a function called `split-to-sentences` that takes an input like this:

`"This is a sentence. And so is this. And this one too."`

and returns:

`["This is a sentence" "And so is this" "And this one too."]`

What I am struggling with is how to iterate over this vector and get the items that aren't the current value. I tried nosing around with `drop` and `remove` but haven't quite figured it out.

I guess one thing I could do is use `first` and `rest` in the loop and `conj` the previous value to the output of rest.

Comment: What do you mean by *items that aren't the current value*?

Comment: The elements in the vector that aren't the one that's "current"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(remove #{current-value} sentences-vector)
```

Comment: This is the solution I'm using. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just use filter:

```
(filter #(not= current-value %) sentences-vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to pass your sentences twice into the `reduce` function...

```
(def sentences ["abcd" "efg" "hijk" "lmnop" "qrs" "tuv" "wx" "y&z"])

(reduce
  (fn [[prev [curr & foll]] _]
    (let [aren't-current-value (concat prev foll)]
      (println aren't-current-value) ;use it here
      [(conj prev curr) foll]))
  [[] sentences]
  sentences)
```

...once to see the following ones, and once to iterate.

Comment: changed to `[prev [curr & foll]]` in line 4

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want something like this function:

```
(defn without-each [x]
  (map (fn [i] (concat (subvec x 0 i) (subvec x (inc i))))
       (range (count x))))
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> (def x ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
>>> (without-each x)
==> (("bar" "baz") ("foo" "baz") ("foo" "bar"))
```

The returned elements are lazily concatenated, which is why they are not vectors. This is desirable, since true vector concatenation (e.g. (into a b)) is O(n).

Because subvec uses sharing with the original sequence this should not use an excessive amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`subvec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subvec) or [`pop`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pop) because both operate very quickly on vectors.